# On the measure of the partial trajectory of a square-filling curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu_2$ denote the usual Lebesgue measure on the square $[0,1]^2$, and let $\gamma: [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ be any continuous surjective map (i.e. a square-filling curve).

Is the function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by
$$f(t)= \mu_2 (\gamma ([0,t]))$$
continuous?

My try: by contradiction, I suppose that there is some discontinuity point $t_0$. Clearly $f$ is an increasing function, so that we have a jump at $t_0$. I would like to use this fact to conclude that $\gamma$ is discontinuous at $t_0$, but I got stuck.

Comment: Did you understand my answer or do you still claim there are problems with it?

Comment: @zhw. I don't understand it, and I am not convinced about that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $0\le r \le 1,$ define $\omega (r)= \sup_{|t-s|\le r} |\gamma (t) - \gamma (s)|.$ Then if $s\le t,$

$$\gamma ([0,t]) \subset \gamma ([0, s]) \cup \overline {B}(\gamma (s),\omega (t-s)).$$

Comment: This need not to be true: a counterexample is any curve $\gamma$ locally constant at $0$.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. As far as I can see, the above is just uniform continuity.